# How to model / control a FCCM buck (variable frequency)

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, buck

I am trying to control the voltage of a buck in FCCM mode (where the half bridge grounds the inductor until the inductor current goes negative by X mA, and then turns it on again), but I am suffering to understand how can I model/control it, this is my first time trying to do digital power.

The microcontroller only controls the on time (and so the inductor peak current, as it can be calculated based on the delta of the actual input and output voltages), but it have no control over the switching frequency, as it is defined by the output current, output voltage and the delta of the input and output voltages...

My main problem is that all materials teaching how to model and control bucks are for fixed frequency bucks where you choose your switching and sampling frequency for the control loop, and I have no idea for what to search / where to start.

How can I define my ideal sampling frequency (is this acceptable to have a fixed sample/control frequency? this frequency could be lower than the maximum operating frequency?) and how can I model and control this kind of buck?
Explanations and suggestions of learning materials for this specific control mode are appreciated!

Thank you!

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjLHxX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Is it a constant-on-time (COT) control for this buck converter? In a fixed-frequency design, the sampling and switching frequencies are usually equal.

Comment: What controls M1? What controls M2? Be clear.

Comment: This looks like a classical sync-rectified buck converter whose MOSFETs are driven by the µcontroller I assume.

Comment: @Andyaka both MOSFETs are controlled by the microcontroller, but the transition from M2 to M1 activation (disconnecting ground and connecting Vin to the inductor) is controlled by the inductor current, it only happens when the inductor current goes negative

Comment: And therefore, presumably, you have a load range that is valid for this type of operation? If you said the MOSFETs change over when inductor current immediately hits zero amps then you have BCM operation - do you understand that?

Comment: Hi @Andyaka, yes, it should always operate in BCM mode, actually it is FCCM mode (where the current always goes a bit negative before commuting), and I know the maximum and minimum currents, but the

Comment: Hi @Andyaka, yes, it should always operate in BCM mode, actually it is FCCM mode (where the current always goes a bit negative before commuting), and I know the maximum and minimum currents, but the problem is that the operating frequency depends on the load, input and output voltages, so I have no "control" over the frequency, that's why I don't understand how could I model or control this system, preferably with a fixed sampling & control frequency (so my CPU will not be overwhelmed if the frequency goes too high)

Comment: Hi @VerbalKint, actually I don't know how to name it, it is a FCCM buck (kind of BCM), but the ON time is determined by the microcontroller and the OFF time is determined by the inductor negative current, so I dont think this could be named "COT" control, right?' And is this case the switching frequency is variable and not controlled, but I would like to control it with a fixed sample/control frequency, even if it is not the best performance, as long as it is stable it is ok

Comment: If the upper-side switch turns on again when the inductor current hits zero, then this is indeed borderline conduction mode (also known as boundary conduction mode or critical conduction mode, CrM). The switching frequency depends on operating conditions and you will probably have to synchronize the µcontroller for proper sampling. If the µcontroller determines the on-time independently from the inductor current, this is voltage-mode control and there must be a digital pulse-width modulator. Before attempting to stabilize this converter, you need it control-to-output transfer function.